# Passport not setting cookies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to assign the user to a cookie when someone logs in, but looks like passport is not assigning the data to the cookie. Below you can find the code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(passport.initialize());

//Use session
app.use(passport.session({ secret: '=Mx;D5F}t&iJZ&w-g;FLK:%QavZgZt', cookie: { maxAge: 0 }, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))

app.use(express.static('server/public'));


//Set view engine
app.set('views', 'server/views')
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


//Set passport local strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" },
  function (email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'email': email }, async function (err, user) {
      console.log('user requested password caught in passport: ', password);
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, console.log('Wrong username'));
      }
      return await user.validatePassword(password, function (err, result) {
        if (err || !result) return done(null, false, console.log('Wrong Password'));
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));

// serialize user object
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

// deserialize user object
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  })
});
```

and this is the login route:

```
//Route for user login
app.post('/auth/local/signin',
  function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(user);

      if (err) {
        console.log('passport.authenticate: error')
      } else if (!user) {
        console.log('passport.authenticate: user')
      } else {
        console.log('next handler')
        console.log('Cookie assigned: ' + req.user)
        return res.redirect('/dashboard')
      }

      return res.redirect('/login')

    })(req, res, next)
  }
)
```

As you can see, I have tried to log req.user which is giving me back undefined.

However, the console.log(user) gives me back the user from the DB, which is what I want.

Comment: The request is from express not from passport. For cookies you should check `req.cookies`

Comment: @DarknessZX I have tried with console.log('Cookie assigned: ', req.cookies) and it's returning Cookie assigned:  [Object: null prototype] {}

Comment: Did you try increase `maxAge` ?